# Got access to SWD, but I need to identify the chip

Tags: debugging, hardware, firmware-analysis

I was able to connect to the chip via SWD/openocd, but I can't figure out what chip it is (says SM9PQ1 2322-52 on chip, googled but cant find anything). I'm hoping to download the firmware after I connect to the chip using the correct config file for openocd. Is there any way I can find out what chip it is? The chip does video compression by the way.

```
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477

> dap info
AP # 0x0
        AP ID register 0x24770011
        Type is MEM-AP AHB3
MEM-AP BASE 0xe00ff003
        Valid ROM table present
        Component base address 0xe00ff000
        Peripheral ID 0x04000bb4c4
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x4c4, Cortex-M4 ROM (ROM Table)
        Component class is 0x1, ROM table
        MEMTYPE system memory present on bus
    ROMTABLE[0x0] = 0xfff0f003
        Component base address 0xe000e000
        Peripheral ID 0x04000bb00c
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x00c, Cortex-M4 SCS (System Control Space)
        Component class is 0xe, Generic IP component
    ROMTABLE[0x4] = 0xfff02003
        Component base address 0xe0001000
        Peripheral ID 0x04003bb002
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x002, Cortex-M3 DWT (Data Watchpoint and Trace)
        Component class is 0xe, Generic IP component
    ROMTABLE[0x8] = 0xfff03003
        Component base address 0xe0002000
        Peripheral ID 0x04002bb003
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x003, Cortex-M3 FPB (Flash Patch and Breakpoint)
        Component class is 0xe, Generic IP component
    ROMTABLE[0xc] = 0xfff01003
        Component base address 0xe0000000
        Peripheral ID 0x04003bb001
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x001, Cortex-M3 ITM (Instrumentation Trace Module)
        Component class is 0xe, Generic IP component
    ROMTABLE[0x10] = 0xfff41003
        Component base address 0xe0040000
        Peripheral ID 0x04000bb9a1
        Designer is 0x23b, ARM Ltd
        Part is 0x9a1, Cortex-M4 TPIU (Trace Port Interface Unit)
        Component class is 0x9, CoreSight component
        Type is 0x11, Trace Sink, Port
    ROMTABLE[0x14] = 0xfff42002
        Component not present
    ROMTABLE[0x18] = 0x00000000
        End of ROM table
```

[image: chip]

Comment: Can you add a link to photo of the chip? We need to know a lot more about the number of pins, how it's connected and type of chip.

Comment: @not2qubit https://i.stack.imgur.com/C00Ze.jpg  it's the main microcontroller on the board. The board streams video over WiFi.

Comment: Who makes the board?

Comment: The board came from a cheap drone made in China (E88 drone) @not2qubit